# Grobid returning 500 type error

Tags: python, grobid

I am trying to use Grobid which is built in my local machine, but this script is print a 500 error. Whereas it works fine when I do it from the CLI using Curl. Help please!

```
    import requests

    url = 'http://localhost:8080/processHeaderDocument'
    files={'file': open('file.pdf', 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url,files=files)
    print r.status_code
```

Comment: it's returning a 500 status code, there must be an error generated on the server which can give more information.

Comment: Please also add an example on how you are using curl to upload a file.

Comment: `curl -v --form input=@./file.pdf localhost:8080/processHeaderDocument`

Comment: org.grobid.service.process.GrobidRestProcessFiles: An unexpected exception occured: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] org.grobid.core.utilities.IOUtilities: Error while deleting the temporary file: 
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I see that with curl you are submitting form with a `input` field, while in code you are submitting file under `file`. You should really consult server logs on what Grobid thinks on your form.

Answer (score 2):

That works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/processHeaderDocument'
multipart_form_data = {
    'input': open('file.pdf', 'rb')
}
r = requests.post(url, files=multipart_form_data)

assert response.status_code == 200, response.content
print(response.content)


# extracting xml
from lxml import objectify
root = objectify.fromstring(response.content)
title = root.teiHeader.fileDesc.titleStmt.title
```